# Draw straight line on google bar chart (combo)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm kinda bound to use google charts for one of my projects. What I need is, to display a bar chart, and in the bars a line intersecting each bar the represents another value.  If you look at the jsfiddle below, you'll notice that the line chart only intersects the bars at the middle and continues to move forward towards other bars.

https://jsfiddle.net/ark7qbsc/

I would instead have, for example if you look at "Apples", for the line to intersect the entire bar (from start to finish) at y=2.5 and end within the bar, not to linger in the white spaces, nor make its way to the other bars.

Could anyone help me with this (Using only google charts.)

I've tired to inject null values after each data row, that at least removes the line from the white spaces. However, now there is just a dot on the centre of the bar. Looking a way to extend that to the entire bar width.

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

        function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Fruit', 'Jane', 'Average'],
           ['Apples', 3, 2.5],
           ['Oranges', 2, 1.5],
           ['Pears', 4, 3],
           ['Bananas', 3, 2],
           ['Plums', 4, 3]      
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
           title : 'Fruits distribution',
           vAxis: {title: 'Fruits'},
           hAxis: {title: 'Person'},
           seriesType: 'bars',
           series: {1:{type: 'line'}}
        };

        // Instantiate and draw the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Can't seem to get a line to be contained in the bar, from start to finish

Answer (score 1):

not possible using standard methods / options,
but we can draw custom lines on the chart's ready event.

add nulls in between the rows to break the line.

```
 ['Fruit', 'Jane', 'Average'],
 ['Apples', 3, 2.5],
 [null, null, null],
 ['Oranges', 2, 1.5],
 [null, null, null],
```

we can use the following option to bring the bars closer together.

```
bar: {
  groupWidth: '95%'
},
```

then we can use the circles to place the custom lines.
and we can use the chart's layout interface to find the width of the bars.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Fruit', 'Jane', 'Average'],
     ['Apples', 3, 2.5],
     [null, null, null],
     ['Oranges', 2, 1.5],
     [null, null, null],
     ['Pears', 4, 3],
     [null, null, null],
     ['Bananas', 3, 2],
     [null, null, null],
     ['Plums', 4, 3]
  ]);

  var options = {
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '95%'
    },
    title : 'Fruits distribution',
    vAxis: {title: 'Fruits'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Person'},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {1:{type: 'line'}}
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // get chart layout and svg
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var svg = document.querySelector('#chart_div svg');
    var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;

    // process each circle
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('circle'), function(circle, index) {
      // find width of the bar
      var bounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('bar#0#' + (index * 2));

      // create line
      var line = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect');
      line.setAttribute('x', parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cx')) - (bounds.width / 2));
      line.setAttribute('y', parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cy')));
      line.setAttribute('width', bounds.width);
      line.setAttribute('height', 1);
      line.setAttribute('stroke', circle.getAttribute('fill'));
      line.setAttribute('stroke-width', 2);
      line.setAttribute('fill', circle.getAttribute('fill'));
      circle.parentNode.appendChild(line);
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped! I decided to go with the circles (instead of lines) but this really helped with conceptually understanding some things.